# CMake Intel Fortran Compiler is not able to compile a simple program

Tags: compilation, cmake, intel-fortran

I am using CMake to prepare a Fortran project under Windows. I have installed some inlet Fortran compiler with VC2015, and when I `cmake`  have the following error

```
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: D:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/ifc.exe
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: D:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/ifc.exe  -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/CMakeTestFortranCompiler.cmake:54 (message):
  The Fortran compiler "D:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
  14.0/VC/bin/ifc.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: D:/Dev/plaf/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

  Run Build Command:"nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_f7da8\fast"

        "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" -f
  CMakeFiles\cmTC_f7da8.dir\build.make /nologo -L
  CMakeFiles\cmTC_f7da8.dir\build

  Building Fortran object
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_f7da8.dir/testFortranCompiler.f.obj

        "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\ifc.exe" -c
  D:\Dev\plaf\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testFortranCompiler.f -o
  CMakeFiles\cmTC_f7da8.dir\testFortranCompiler.f.obj

  usage: D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\ifc.exe
  [subcommand] [options...]

    subcommands:
      OBJ            Convert an interface file into a dummy object file which can be archived into a static lib.
      EMBED          Embed an interface file into an existing static lib, producing a new lib.
      EXTRACT        Extract an embedded interface file from an existing static lib, producing the ifc.
      LOCATE         Find all embedded interface files and print their offset + size to stdout.

  NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
  14.0\VC\bin\ifc.exe"' : return code '0x1'
```

My understanding of the error (correct me if I am wrong), is that cmake is using the compiler with the wrong flags, hence during the sample program compilation it just doesn't work.

How can I fix that ? (The error seems different from what I have seen in most other posts)

Comment: If you mean from Visual studio, yes I just created a new fortran hello world project, it compiles and runs without problem.

Comment: What's your CMake version? Sometimes the need to tweak something to work with newer versions.

Comment: This could be a case of mistaken identity. VS 2015 includes a new tool called `ifc.exe` and it is entirely possible that `cmake` is mistaking this exe as the Fortran compiler (`ifort` used to be known as `ifc`). If that is really the case, your best bet would be to downgrade to VS2013 and let the cmake developers know.

Answer (score 0):

it happened by me when I used MinGW to compile. The solution is to choose "MinGW Makefiles" instead of Visual Studio in the configure of CMake